# How can i find used tables names in Tableau without using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, database, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and don't want to mess the database. Is there a safe way to find out the table names from the dataset used to build a tableau dashboard?

Comment: One of the first concepts I learned with this tool; "Tableau can not Create, Update, or Delete database records."  If Tableau is your only access to the database, you can only screw up how you connect,  Records in the database are safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing what you see but generally, the dimensions on the left panel are organized in a table hierarchy.  In the image below you can see three tables.  One has been expanded to show the fields (dimensions) used. The other two tables can be expanded by clicking on the >
[image]